# How do I transfer music files to Nexus 4

Tags: file-transfer, nexus-4

I plugged in Nexus 4 to my windows machine(XP Service Pack 2) and it didnt recognise or install any software automatically. I downloaded Google USB Driver from SDK Kit and installed it and now it shows up as recognised device in the Device Manager, but how do I copy files to Phones Storage ? There s no send to option as its not connected as a USB mass storage(which is not there in this device as well)

Comment: AFAIK the *Nexus 4* does not use UMS but MTP instead. On Windows, it should show up directly in the Explorer. Having neither a *Nexus 4* nor Windows, I can only refer to hear-say -- and refer you to [How To - Connect Nexus 4 to XP like MTP device - xda-developers](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2165550)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The XDA article [How To - Connect Nexus 4 to XP like MTP device](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2165550) describes the steps needed **for Windows XP** as follows:

> 1. Connect your Nexus to PC.
> 2. Go to My Computer>Properties>Device Manager and double click on MTP device
> 3. Go to Details and copy (Ctr+C) info like (USB\VID_18D1&PID_4EE2&MI_00) (you can copy it from here too, if it is identically)
> 4. Unplug Nexus from PC.
> 5. Go to C:\Windows\inf folder (it's hidden)
> 6. Find a file "wpdmtp.inf" and open it with any text editor (Notepad)
> 7. Modify or Paste (Ctrl+P) what did you copy at step "3" as bottom I showed.

```
; Installation inf for devices supporting Media Transfer Protocol (MTP)
;
; Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.
;

[Version]
Signature="$WINDOWS NT$"
Class=WPD
ClassGUID={EEC5AD98-8080-425f-922A-DABF3DE3F69A}
Provider=%Msft%
LayoutFile=layout.inf
DriverVer=02/22/2006,5.2.5326.4762

[DestinationDirs]
MTP.Files.Kernel = 12
MTP.Files.XPRT_USB = 11
MTP.Files.Core = 11
MTP.Files.UMDFDDriver = 12,UMDF ; copy to system32\drivers\umdf
[Manufacturer]
%MfgName%=Generic,NTx86,NTamd64
;
;Device is identified by Microsoft OS descriptor
;If your device does not support it, use specific VID & PID for identification
;
[Generic.NTx86]
%GenericMTP.DeviceDesc%=MTP, USB\MS_COMP_MTP
%GenericMTP.DeviceDesc%=MTP, USB\VID_18D1&PID_4EE2&MI_00
;
[Generic.NTamd64]
%GenericMTP.DeviceDesc%=MTP, USB\MS_COMP_MTP
%GenericMTP.DeviceDesc%=MTP, USB\VID_18D1&PID_4EE2&MI_00
```

> 1. Save and close the file.
> 2. Connect your Nexus to PC
> 3. Go to Device Manager and update MTP driver.
> 4. Tick chekbox "Install the software automatically (Recomenden)" on driver installation dialog and install driver.
>      Wait for a moment and you can see Nexus 4 like an MTP device.

Now you should see the MTP device, and be able to transfer files to it.

Hope this solves your issue :)

Comment: Yes this helped, but I got 2 problems, 1> File was nt there - So downloaded WIn Player 11 and it was solved. 2> I had installed ADB driver before, so when I uninstalled that and tried to install driver it always instalelled ADB driver instead of MTP. So instead I chose Manual Location and it gave 2 options install as ADB or MTP and I chose as MTP and all is good now :) Thanks for that link ! Didnt come across that link while I was googling,

Comment: Glad it helped -- and thanks for the updated details!